# Using $.Deferred() with nested $.each statements

Tags: sharepoint, jquery-deferred

I am working with SharePoint making JSOM calls. I need to get results and not move on until ALL data is retrieved. I have tried so many examples (none are complete enough for me to understand how to tailor to my issue with nested $.each loop statements. I seem to get close, but never anything working correctly.

I have edited my actual code (minus the top 3 variables as they are passed in from another page) to incorporate Tomalak's work so it we can figure it out better. Currently, the results are coming up with empty objects. Trying to figure out what I;m doing wrong.

**[EDITED 06 AUG 2018]**
Finally got it to work. there was only two tiny problems I found with the provided code :-). I will try and bold them.

```
var fya = [2008,2009]; //Fiscal Year Array which we use to know what lists to look at
var assignedRecords = []; //Global Reusable Variable
var assignedCourses = ['Math','Science','Reading']; //There might not be records who are associated with a particular course in each list. Wee need to pull the student records (assignedRecords) assoiciated with the above in 2008 and 2009.

SP.ClientContext.prototype.executeQueryPromise = function (items) {
    var result = $.Deferred();
    this.load(items);
    this.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) { result.resolve(items) }, 
        function (sender, args) { result.reject(args) });
    return result.promise();
};
```

**Move 'var arr = [];' outside of arrayFromCollection**
**Add 'var' to the e variable in that same function**

```
var arr = [];
function arrayFromCollection(coll) {
    var e = coll.getEnumerator();
    while (e.moveNext()) arr.push(e.get_current());
    return arr;
};

function queryListPromise(title, course) {
    var list = hostWeb.get_lists().getByTitle(title);
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where>'
        + '<Eq><FieldRef Name="Course"/><Value Type="Text">' + course + '</Value></Eq>'
        + '</Where></Query></View>');
    return context.executeQueryPromise(list.getItems(camlQuery)).then(arrayFromCollection);
};

function GetAssignedApplications() {
    assignedRecords = []; //Need to start empty
    var myCourses = assignedCourses;

    $.each(myCourses, function (i, myCoursesItem) {
        var courseName = myCoursesItem.get_lookupValue();
```

**Change '$.forEach' to '$.each'**

```
        $.each(fya, function (n, fyaItem) {
            var listTitle = "FY" + String(fyaItem).substring(2); //FY18 & FY19 are the names of the actual lists.
            assignedRecords.push(queryListPromise(listTitle, courseName));
        });
    });

    $.when(assignedRecords).then(function (results) {
        return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], results);
    }).then(function (items) {
        items.forEach(function (item) {
            var a = item; //item is empty and this actually runs before arrayFromCollection and it returns duplicate records (4) when there is only 2.
        });
    }).fail(onError);
};
```

Comment: Why are the same chapters queried for every book?

Comment: I was trying to think generically..LOL. Guess not the best. Better to say arr1 and arr2. Either array can change. There are no set count to either. So say books[1] can have chapters[20], then books[2] might have chapters[12].

Comment: Really, the books and chapters should not have been passed to the function. They already exist and where obtained previously.

Comment: Could you change the sample to reflect that?

Comment: Did so. So basically, it should search 2 lists (x and y). Inside those 2 lists, a, b, and/or c are all possible outcomes. When they are the result is pushed to one collection. The number of lists to look in will expand, so it is never a set number.

Comment: I've attempted an answer. Disclaimer, I have never worked with the SharePoint JS client library and cannot really test the code, take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first things first, waiting on multiple promises in jQuery is done with `$.when()`.

```
$.when(p1, p2, p3).then(function (results) {
    // results is an array of length 3
});
```

In order to make this work with a variable argument count, we use `Function#apply`:

```
var promises = [p1, p2, p3]; // could be be of any length now

$.when.apply($, promises).then(function () {
    var results = [].slice.call(arguments);
    // results is an array of the same length as promises
});
```

In order to make this reusable, let's call that `$.whenAll`:

```
$.whenAll = function (promises) {
    return $.when.apply($, promises).then(function () {
        return [].slice.call(arguments);
    });
};
```

Now we can do:

```
$.whenAll([p1, p2, p3]).then(function (results) {
    // results is an array of length 3
});
```

---

Next, we need to turn the callback-based `executeQueryAsync()` into a promise-based function. In general, promisification follows this scheme:

```
function somethingPromise(args) {
    var result = $.Deferred();
    somethingAsync(/* onSuccess */ result.resolve, /* onError */ result.reject);
    return result.promise();
}
```

This expects that the onSuccess and onError handlers receive data as arguments. That's not the case with `executeQueryAsync` - it modifies the `items` directly. However, we still want to resolve the promise with `items`, so we need to do that explicitly.

Let's slap that onto the `SP.ClientContext` prototype right-away for re-use.

```
SP.ClientContext.prototype.executeQueryPromise = function (items) {
    var result = $.Deferred();
    this.load(items);
    this.executeQueryAsync(
        function (sender, args) { result.resolve(items); },
        function (sender, args) { result.reject(args); }
    );
    return result.promise();
};
```

---

Next we should set up a helper that turns those unwieldy collections into something usable.

```
function arrayFromCollection(coll) {
    var arr = [], e = coll.getEnumerator();
    while (e.moveNext()) arr.push(e.get_current());
    return arr;
}
```

---

With that all done, we can extract a function that takes a title and returns a promise for an item array.

```
function queryListPromise(title) {
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(title);
    var q = new SP.CamlQuery();
    //...
    return ctx.executeQueryPromise(list.getItems(q)).then(arrayFromCollection);
}
```

---

And finally, since you want a flat list of items, we should start with a flat list of queries:

```
function GetNextFunction() {
    var queries = [];

    // build flat list of queries
    $.each(arr1, function(i, arr1Item) {
        $.each(arr2, function(n, arr2Item) {
            queries.push(queryListPromise(arr2Item));
        });
    });

    // wait on all queries
    $.whenAll(queries).then(function (results) {
        // flatten incoming array of arrays
        return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], results);
    }).then(function (items) {
        // items contains all items from all queries
        items.forEach(function (item) { /* ... */ });
    }).fail(onError);
}
```

Here `queries` becomes a flat array of promises, each promise will resolve to an array of items. Therefore, `results` will be an array of arrays of items.

Comment: WOW! Awesome! I am going to try and implement today and tomorrow. i will get back with finding s and hopefully can mark this answered. This certainly looks promising :-) Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully there is not too much wrong, I was winging it way too much for my tastes with regard to the SP library.

Comment: I do not see a ...prototype.executeQueryPromise, only a .prototype.executeQueryAsync. Also, having a small issue understanding when/where/how I kick this whole thing off? Pretend I am very ignorant and my cursor is currently within a function and right before the close of that function, I need to start this whole process. :-)

Comment: What do you mean "see"? It's not there until you add it. My code adds it, unless you are not running that part. My code samples above are not just explanatory, you need to run the relevant ones. :)

Comment: Okay, will continue to decipher. Just having a difficult time figuring where to start using my example that I posted in the beginning. You've done a lot. Sorry to be a bother.

Comment: I know it's a lot to take in, especially if you have no real understanding of how promises work. I tried to build up a logical chain - the last code sample is your very own function, just rewritten with all the things I have introduced before. That's to say, you kick this whole thing off by running it. I admit I thought this was obvious, but obviously it wasn't. :)

Comment: Also, I expect this code to fail initially. Maybe subtly, maybe hard. I can't really test it, and as I said, I have zero experience with the SP client library, all I have is the MSDN. My answer does two things. 1) It explains how to turn a callback-based function into a promise-based one. Any function, really, it always works in the same way. And 2) It tries to create re-usable utilities that might be helpful in other code code you write. So my suggestion would be to read it both ways. Top to bottom to see all the moving parts, and bottom to top to understand the code of `GetNextFunction`.

Comment: Okay. So far it is working. Had to change $.forEach to just $.each. I am at the $.whenAll part. and get an error. Did you mean just $.when or is the another something I need to use to ensure 'all'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177377/discussion-between-keltanis-and-tomalak).